# Android - Arraylist size always zero

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i try to make a application. i use facebook sdk and i can login with facebook. App is getting movies with user likes. i can do this with graph api and i can add all name of movie into arraylist. Everything is OK so far. but when i try to access in onCreate method that arraylist always null. When i am use debug i can see the json value. How can i solve this. i know my english is not good i am trying to explain my issue. i could hope :)

```
public class list extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> movieList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void getInfo(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                        try {
                            JSONObject movies = jsonObject.getJSONObject("movies");
                            JSONArray data = movies.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i<data.length();i++){
                                JSONObject objectData = data.getJSONObject(i);
                                String movieName = objectData.getString("name");
                                movieList.add(movieName);
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "movies");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        getInfo();

        this.setTitle(movieList.get(0));



    }
}
```

Comment: As `executeAsync()` is called, i presume that `this.setTitle()` runs way before that async request is finished...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's empty cause the request is async and it hasn't end when you try to access the array... try accessing it at onCompleted

Comment: 0 is just example. if i want to fill listView with arraylist. what can i do ? i think i have to fill again onCompleted. is it correct ?

Comment: yes do it onCompleted...it was my bad i wrote 0, i meant empty